# How do you find the smallest legitimate encryption exponent when you are only give a p and q value in a given range?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, cryptography

I have been given this as an assignment question but I'm not sure approach it.

EDIT: Sorry I should have added more details. It is a cryptosystem using the RSA scheme. p and q are both old prime numbers and the encryption exponent must be greater than 1000.

Comment: What encryption protocol are you using? What are $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Please provide the encryption / decryption equations in $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Assuming you talk about RSA with $p,q$ odd primes: find the smallest odd $e \ge 3$ with $\gcd(p-1,e)=1, \gcd(q-1,e)=1$

Comment: @gammatester: I suppose that can be made an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Taking up @ccorn's suggestion, here is my slighty expanded comment as an answer:

With $p,q$ odd primes and $p\ne q$ the restrictions for the public RSA exponent $e$ is $1 < e < \varphi(pq)$ and $\gcd(e, \varphi(pq))=1.$ Because you have a more restrictive lower bound, your smallest exponent $e$ can be found as the smallest odd $e > 1000$ with $\gcd(e, p-1)=1$ 
and $\gcd(e, q-1)=1$ or using one gcd and larger numbers $\gcd(e, (p-1)(q-1))=1$.

You do not have to check even $e$ because $\varphi(pq)$ is even and therefor the gcd would be at least 2.

**Edit:** In most case you get $e$ simply by computing the gcd, computing gcds is fast. If it is not 1, go to the next possible value $e+2$. There $\varphi(\varphi(pq))$ legitimate values (if you include the $e<1000$). In many of your practical cases $e=1001$ will work.

An example for the small values $p=97, q=101.$ You have $\varphi(pq)=9600$ and $\varphi(\varphi(pq))=2560$, i.e. here roughly $52\%\,$ of all odd values are legitimate and $\gcd(1001,9600)=1$. If you would start at $e=3$ you get
$$\gcd(3,9600)=3,\quad\gcd(5,9600)=5,\quad\gcd(7,9600)=1$$

An example where $e=1001$ is not legitimate is $p=97,\, q=113.$ Here you have $\varphi(pq)=10752\,$ and $\gcd(1001, 10752)=7,\,$ but the next value works $\gcd(1003, 10752)=1.$

Comment: Once I have it set up as gcd(e,(p−1)(q−1)) = 1 and e > 1000, how I can rearrange solve for e?

Comment: I have edited-in my former comment.